# TabHost not filling entire screen when calculating tab width according to screen width

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I have a `TabHost` containing five tabs within a horizontal `ScrollView`. I want all tabs to have the same size with a minimum size of 83dp. If the fifth tab fits on screen, all tabs are widened to fill the entire screen. Here is the code to achieve this:

```
int tabMinWidth = (int) (83 * density);
int tabWidth = tabMinWidth
int nrOfTabs = displayMetrics.widthPixels / tabMinWidth;
if (nrOfTabs > 4)
    tabWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels / 5;
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).getLayoutParams().width = tabWidth;
```

Basically the code works fine. However, not the entire screen width is used by the tabs. Example: five tabs with 96px do not fill a 320x480 screen in landscape mode (about 20px unused space), although 96 x 5 is exactly 480. How can I improve the code so that the tabs really fill the entire screen?

<strike>UPDATE:
Solution: I found that resizing each tab by about 4-5% works quite well:</strike>

```
tabWidth = (int) (tabWidth *1.04);
```

UPDATE 2:
I think I found the cause of the problem. The tabs have a negative right and left margin. Considering these margins solves the problem and the `TabHost` fills exactly the whole screen.

Comment: are there gaps between tab buttons? that might be the 20px

Comment: Yes, there are small gaps between the tabs but I doubt that they are the reason for the unnused space. They should cause the TabHost to be broader (width + gap) and not too small. I somehow fixed the problem now by multiplying `tabWidth` by 1.04. However, this is just an approximation and still needs improvement.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the `android:fillViewport="true"` of the horizontal scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using buttons will work.

When I use tabs, I normally just hide the tabwidget tag by setting android visibility as gone.

And add buttons to act as the tab buttons like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">        
        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"  
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dip" 
            android:layout_weight="1.0"/> 
        <FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 
            <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs" android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:visibility="gone"/> 
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
                android:layout_height="64dip"> 
                <Button android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="0dip"  
                    android:layout_weight="1.0" 
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_tab_artists"  
                    android:id="@+id/artist_id" android:onClick="tabHandler"/> 
                <Button android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="0dip"  
                    android:layout_weight="1.0" 
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_tab_artists"  
                    android:id="@+id/album_id" android:onClick="tabHandler"/>
            </LinearLayout>  
        </FrameLayout> 
    </LinearLayout> 
</TabHost>
```

and I add a button click handler

```
public void tabHandler(View target){ 
    artistButton.setSelected(false); 
    albumButton.setSelected(false); 
    songButton.setSelected(false); 
    if(target.getId() == R.id.artist_id){ 
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0); 
        artistButton.setSelected(true); 
    } else if(target.getId() == R.id.album_id){ 
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(1); 
        albumButton.setSelected(true); 
    }
}
```

This makes it easier to customize tab buttons. You will need to try it out as im haven't really tried tabs in a horizontalscrollview.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I do not want to handle the tabs on my own. Its just overkill for my purpose. I will use the approximation as described above.